# iframe not working, on kiwiirc embed

Tags: php, html, iframe, irc, kiwi-irc

I was writing a long .php website and thought about embedding kiwiirc. The issue is, I keep getting an empty frame. The problem is even worse when I figured out that iframe for kiwiirc.com itself works, but not for the full embed code (example for not working: https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.kiwiirc.com/?&theme=basic#your_channel ). Other sites work as expected too, the only issue I appear to have with is their own embed links. If I open their link in a browser, it works. I'm trying to run it on localhost.

Example of code not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<iframe src="https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.kiwiirc.com/?&theme=basic#your_channel" style="border:0; width:100%; height:450px;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Kiwiirc's embed links: https://kiwiirc.com/embedding

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1pw4geLu/ - check your browser console for errors.

Comment: You are right, I am receiving: Load denied by X-Frame-Options, not sure why

Comment: No, excuse me, I'm getting: "Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead." in "_dist-editor.js:2:27387"

Comment: In my own html file I get no errors after I include "<meta charset="UTF-8">". But iframe for this specific url still doesn't work.

Comment: It appears to be my browser, tried it in chromium. I'm generally using Firefox with a lot of addons. What confuses me is that other sites work, but hey at least it's not the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a Kiwi applet in a frame or iframe you have to enable third party cookies because the browser sees two different domains. Your domain and the domain where the cookies come from (your embedded applet)

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, nothing wrong with the code. I installed chromium and tested it, and it worked. Usually using firefox with a lot of addons, odd thing being that all other embeds worked, and so this specific url when opened in a new tab.

I know it's not much of an answer, but it's browser's fault.